# writeStartElement has prvoide namespaceURI, why need another writeNamespace?

Tags: java, xml, stax

The code:

```
XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
writer.writeStartDocument("1.0");
writer.writeCharacters("\n");
writer.writeStartElement("ns1", "sample", "http://www.e.com/ns1");
writer.writeNamespace("ns1", "http://www.e.com/ns1");
writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndDocument();
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns1:sample xmlns:ns1="http://www.e.com/ns1"/>
```

If I delete `writer.writeNamespace("ns1", "http://www.e.com/ns1");`, then the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns1:sample/>
```

What's the effect of the `namespaceURI` parameter of `writeStartElement()`?

Answer (score 1):

Following statement also does prefix binding for you:

```
writer.writeStartElement("ns1", "sample", "http://www.e.com/ns1");
```

If you then use statements without specifying prefix, it will know that prefix should be `ns1`:

```
writer.writeStartElement("http://www.e.com/ns1", "sample2");
writer.writeEndElement();
```

As for `writeNamespace`, you still need to write namespace declaration by yourself.